# jumbotrons side by side are rendering in stack order

Tags: css

I trying to update my website and would like to have two jumbotrons side by side but they keep rendering in stack position?? What am I missing?

borrowed code from another thread:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

         <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-6">
                <h1>Become Awesome</h1>
                <p>Here you will learn how to become awesome.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="{% url 
         'awesome_info' %}">More Info</a>
            </div>
           
            <div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-6">
                <h1>Here you will learn how to become super rad.</h1>
                <p>Tubular dude.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'rad_info' %}" 
          role="button">More Info</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Would you please add the CSS that you are using for this?

Comment: I thought the bootstrap.min.css would automatically work. Would you know how I would have to write the CSS for the jumbtrons to be flush side by side??

Answer (score 0):

Need to change your markup.

> Open snippet in full-screen

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Become Awesome</h1>
        <p>Here you will learn how to become awesome.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="{% url 
 'awesome_info' %}">More Info</a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Here you will learn how to become super rad.</h1>
        <p>Tubular dude.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'rad_info' %}" 
  role="button">More Info</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I click the "Run code snippet" button it still renders stacked? How to write code for them to be side by side/

Comment: sorry when I clicked the open in new window I see it side by side. but in my website it still renders stacked?

Comment: Click Full page on right bottom side of snippet after running the code

Comment: Anuresh, I did see it on full page but my website with that code is not rendering side by side...any ideas why not??

Comment: Could you provide link to your site ?